# Facebook like Button with user authentication

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-like

I am developing a ipad application in that i need to include facebook page like button. I have loaded the button using iframe in `webview`, when user clicked on the button if they already sigh in just count should increment or decrement else pop up will ask them to login first. once they logged in then increment the count automatically.
Any sample for code to do step by step.

Here is my `webview` like button code

```
NSString *likeButtonIframe = @"<iframe src='http://www.facebook.com/plugins/likebox.php?id=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX&amp;width=292&amp;connections=0&amp;stream=false&amp;header=false&amp;height=62' scrolling='no' frameborder=0' style='border:none; overflow:hidden; width:282px; height:62px;' allowTransparency='true'></iframe>";

NSString *likeButtonHtml = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"<HTML><BODY>%@</BODY></HTML>", likeButtonIframe];
[_webView loadHTMLString:likeButtonHtml baseURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@""]];
```

Also i have tried before shows like i will ask him to login first then display the like button and ask them to like.

Comment: simple Need to have facebook page like button in my ipad application. once user clicks on that to ask him login for like

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per Facebook you should not have a like button in the app, that is to avoid spam likes.

Even through we can implement it using iFrame & `UIWebView`.

RayWinderlich has a great [tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/1626/how-to-post-to-a-users-wall-upload-photos-and-add-a-like-button-from-your-iphone-app) for this Facebook Like Button in iOS app.

[Follow this link](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like-box/) to generate a Facebook like frame for your page.

And use accordingly in your app, one limitation is that if user is not logged in it shows a login screen within it. So if your webView is small, it will be issue. Check out the sample from tutorial, and implement as per your requirements.

Answer (score 1):

I used UIWebView's delegate method

```
-(BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType
```

to detect when user does not have active session.
Here is my sample code: https://github.com/gneil90/facebook-likebox-ios-login